# Redux connect "blocks" navigation with react-router-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

In an application using *react*, *redux* and *react-router*, I'm using *react-router-redux* to issue navigation actions. I found that wrapping routes in a component with *connect* blocks navigation.

I made a sample with *CodeSandbox* that illustrates the issue: [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/6v6347p52r).

As is, the navigation doesn't work. However, if in *./components/Routes.jsx*, this line:

```
export default connect(() => ({}), () => ({}))(Routes);
```

Is replaced by:

```
export default Routes;
```

It works.

Any idea how I could use *connect* in a component that wraps routes without breaking navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [troubleshooting](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#my-views-arent-updating-when-something-changes-outside-of-redux) section in react-redux docs.

If you change Routes.jsx export to:

```
export default connect(() => ({}), () => ({}), null, { pure: false })(Routes);
```

it will work.

> This is because connect() implements shouldComponentUpdate by default,
>   assuming that your component will produce the same results given the
>   same props and state.

route changes, but props don't so the view doesn't update.

You could achieve same with `withRouter` hoc.

Answer (score 1):

Not meant to be a duplicate.

I fixed it with `withRouter` like this

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and

```
export default withRouter( connect(mapStateToProps)(App) );
```

See Redux, Router integration docs [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/redux-integration)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever encountered the warning message:

`Warning: You cannot change <Router history>`

Well use `withRouter` from `react-router-dom`

I have searched for this for so long because the Redux was recreating my App.jsx component which has `<Route> </Route>` as parents and this warning just freezes the routing in my app. I wanted to have React/Redux component, because I needed to pass `authenticated` props to the Route component, and redirect base on it, simple.

So `import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'`

and surround your component which is connected to redux with:

`export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(App));`

Something more:
Most of the times if you want to communicate with the router, takes some props, pass something else to it, get history, locations form it and you are using Redux in your app, surround this component with `withRouter` and you will have access to these properties as props.